# Checking quadratic programming solution

Tags: optimization

I want to check if $(0,1,2)$ is the solution to a following problem:
$$x_3\to \min,$$
$$x_1^2+2x_1x_2+2x^2_2-2x_1-x_2-x_3+1\geq 0,$$
$$x_1^2+x_2^2-x_1+x_2-x_3\leq 0,$$
$$x_1^2+x_1-4x_2-x_3+6\leq 0,$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0.$$
Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. 1) By "$x_3 \rightarrow \mathrm{min}$" you mean that you are looking for the triple with minimal $x_3$? 2) How do you know there is exactly one solution? 3) Are you looking for integer solutions of your problem? 4) There is an index missing in the second displayed formula.

Comment: I want to minimize function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_3$. I'm looking for solutions over $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: You could start by checking the KKT conditions (which are necessary but not sufficient). However, proving optimality requires ad-hoc reasoning for nonconvex problems like these.

Comment: The accepted solution assumes integrality while this is not part of this question. If integrality is not assumed, the accepted answer is at least incomplete. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are only looking for integer solutions. Then it is enough to show that no solution with $x_3\in \{0,1\}$ is possible.

Assume $x_3=1$, then the third and fourth displayed formulae become
$$x_1 \geq x_1^2 +x_2^2 +x_2 -1,$$
and
$$4x_2 \geq x_1^2 + x_1 +5.$$

Put together they imply
$$4x_2 \geq x_1^2 +x_2^2+x_2+4,$$
therefore
$$3x_2 \geq 4 +x_2^2.$$

And it is easy to see that the latter inequality has not integer solution. The case $x_3=0$ proceeds along the same lines.\

If you are not only looking at integer solutions, this method implies
$$x_3 \geq \frac{15}{8}.$$

Comment: $x_3$ component in my proposed solution is $2$. How does your answer apply exactly?

Comment: It is trivial that the proposed solution satisfies all the requirements except the minimality. My answer proves the minimality. Does it make it more sense now?